# Getting Internal Server Error (500) with Node.js setup to use HTTPS

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, https

I am using a very simple server script

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/certs/private_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/certs/my_cert.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/certs/my_bundle.ca-bundle'),
}

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(3000,'example.com');
```

This example was taken from https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001603071-How-to-install-a-certificate-on-Node-js.

My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com:3000/$1 [L,P,QSA]
```

The goal is to have all traffic redirect to the server using HTTPS. When I execute the command

```
node server.js
```

There are no errors and the server is listening. When I try to connect via a browser using

```
https://example.com
```

I get an internal server error and I cannot figure out what the problem might be because I cannot figure out how to get any logs from node.js.

If I setup the server to listen over regular HTTP and set the .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect to the site over regular HTTP it works fine. I cannot figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong because when I test the server locally with the certs, it seems to work fine over HTTPS (i.e. https://localhost:3000 even though the browser says the cert is invalid). Any idea what the problem is and anyway to get relevant logs from node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution which seems to work but bear in mind I am a noob.

Just some brief context.

- Godaddy is currently hosting my files (I'm on the cheapest plan).

Instead of trying to setup node.js as an HTTPS server, I simply run it as a regular HTTP server. For SSL capabilities, I install the certs (private key, bundle, etc) using GoDaddy's configuration tool in CPanel called "SSL/TLS". When this is done, I can type:

```
https://example.com
```

and the connection shows as secure. In order to make this work with the regular node.js HTTP server, I had to revise my rewrite rules in the primary .htaccess file. Namely

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off                                   # To ensure no redirect loop
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]        # Redirect to the secure site
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com:3000/$1 [L,P,QSA]      # Internally, however, pass all request to the regular HTTP node.js server listening on port 3000
```

Now I can type any URL in the browser (i.e. www.example.com, example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com) and they all redirect to https://example.com and all the website data is fetched normally over the secure connection according to the browser.